# How to delete ForeignKey field from model safely?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model like this (simplified for relevancy):

```
class Director(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

I just realized that `user_account` needs to be `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`. Making that change will essentially mean *removing* the existing `user_account` field and *creating* the new one.

The problem is that I had bad experience in the past when messing with `ForeignKey` field. To make matters worse, I already created a couple of `Director` objects in the database with the `ForeignKey` linked to `User` objects.

My question is how can I delete, and ultimately change, `user_account` field without causing runtime errors later on?

Additional context: I'm using Django 1.9 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use django `migrations` to do that.

1. Add a `OneToOne` field pointing to the model `User`, you might need to add `related_name` for that.
2. Create one migration that apply the field to database.
3. Create a data migration and copy the `ForeignKey` value from `user_account` to the new field for each `Director`.
4. Delete your `user_account` field in model, then create another migration to apply the deletion to the database.

Comment: When you said "Create a data migration", did you mean something like `migrations.RunPython()`?

Comment: Good answer. This is the migration that I made for future reference (https://gist.github.com/vleong2332/612fa933ffff8aa64063)

Answer (score 2):

`ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` are the same, except `OneToOneField` has a unique constraint. Try changing the field in your models and running `makemigrations` -- I think Django should be smart enough to be able to create the required migration.

Before you start, you need to make sure that there aren't multiple director instances pointing to the same user, because this isn't allowed by a one to one field.

Comment: In the case that I do have multiple directors pointing to the same user, @ShangWang 's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference between `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField`. If you run directly change the model field type, your data will not be disturbed. After changing the model field type, run `makemigrations`.